# Page object design pattern in Angular's e2e tests

Tags: angularjs

Can page object design pattern be implemented in angular e2e or does it follow some other design pattern ?

Comment: A most excellent question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned there is this GitHub project called Astrolabe (by stuplum) which is an extension for protractor that adds page objects to your functional/e2e tests.

https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe

However, at the time of writing this it has some bugs to fix and it seems to be a WIP project.

You can find here a question regarding Page Object pattern alternatives: 
[Page Object pattern and alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106695/page-object-pattern-and-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

The protractor [getting started](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#organizing-real-tests-page-objects) page now has a [section](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#organizing-real-tests-page-objects) about it.

Note protractor is now the AngularJS team [preferred way](http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/09/28/angularjs-test-pyramid/) for e2e testing.

Regarding Astrolabe i don't believe that's the way to go, see for example this [leaking abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) while using `sendKeys` on their [readme](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe#usage)

`signInPage.username.sendKeys('a username'); // will fill the username input with the text 'a username'`

While the proper way would be more like

`signInPage.setUserName('a username');`

I prefer to create my own page objects without the need of any extension like [Andres shows here](https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractorTest/blob/master/scenarios/home-scenario.js)